# Checking and editing a value in isolated storage in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I am trying to check for the word "Alarm" in my isolated storage before saving.

If the word "Alarm" is exist i will change the "Alarm" to "Alarm1" then if "Alarm1" is exist will change to "Alarm2".

How should i go about doing it?

Below is my code but it is not working:

```
if (labelTextBox.Text == "")
{
    try
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            foreach (string label in storage.GetFileNames("*"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(label);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }

    int i = 0;
    i++;
    labelTextBox.Text = "Alarm" + i;
    alarmLabel = (labelTextBox.Text.ToString()).Replace(" ", "_");
}
```

Comment: Are you looking to see if a file named "Alarm" exists? or if any of the files in IS contain the text "Alarm"?

Comment: But if "alarm" exist the next will be "alarm1" to replace it and so on and so for

Comment: Yes, but is "alarm" a file or something in a file?

Comment: is just a name of a file

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings**, which is more appropriated for object (e.r. string) handling.

I made a small sample which makes use of this class:

```
using System;
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace SidekickWP7
{
    public partial class Page1 : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        const string MYALARM = "MyAlarm";

        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page1_Loaded);
        }

        void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int intAlarm = 0;

            Int32.TryParse(Load(MYALARM).ToString(), out intAlarm);

            intAlarm++;

            MessageBox.Show(intAlarm.ToString());

            Save(MYALARM, intAlarm);
        }

        private static object Load(string strKey)
        {
            object objValue;

            if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<object>(strKey, out objValue) == false)
            {
                objValue = String.Empty;
            }

            return objValue;
        }

        private static void Save(string strKey, object objValue)
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[strKey] = objValue;

            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    int highestNumberFound = -1;

    foreach (var fileName in store.GetFileNames())
    {
        if (fileName.StartsWith("alarm"))
        {
            if (fileName == "alarm")
            {
                if (highestNumberFound < 0)
                {
                    highestNumberFound = 0;
                }
            }
            else if (fileName.Length > 5)
            {
                int numb;

                if (int.TryParse(fileName.Substring(5), out numb))
                {
                    if (numb > highestNumberFound)
                    {
                        highestNumberFound = numb;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    string toCreate = "alarm";

    if (++highestNumberFound > 0)
    {
        toCreate += highestNumberFound.ToString();
    }

    store.CreateFile(toCreate);
}
```

Not pretty but it should work.

I storngly suspect that creating empty files with different names isn't the best way to achieve whatever it is that you're trying to do though.

Comment: Hi i have tried it. But it also reach alarm1.. and keep repeating as alarm1. it didnt go up to alarm2, alarm3

Comment: @ben it sounds likte the original file isn't being deleted then. What have you done to debug the issue?

Comment: Hmm i didnt want to delete the original file. I wanted something like if there is a file named "alarm" den my next file will be named as "alarm1" instead. The original "alarm" will still be there. sorry